# invalid argument supplied for foreach() in -----joomla

Tags: php, joomla

This Is My Full Error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/techandw/public_html/plugins/system/helix/shortcodes/column.php on line 31
```

31 line is

```
foreach ($columnArray as $key=>$value) $html .='<div class=' . $value['class'] . '>' . do_shortcode($value['content']) . '</div>';
```

Can anyone help  me how i can fix this error

Comment: `$columnArray ` isn't array. You need to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

Check `$columnArray` variable it is not passing as `array`. You can check using `var_dump`

```
 var_dump($columnArray);
```

It is good practice to check array before using it.

```
if(!empty($columnArray)) {
        foreach ($columnArray as $key=>$value) {

         ---
     }

}
```

Comment: Roopenda i Dont know php Can u pls Do it for me?

Comment: can i have ur email id? i will send u complete column.php file